# How do you handle a PHP session update on a form submit?

Tags: php, session

Hey Guys,
I have this form that when I submit will put into a session variable the items in the form.  The form has a self target so after clicking submit, it just refreshes the page.

But I need the page to be refreshed with the newly added session variable items to be echo'd back out.  Currently I would need to click refresh again for it to echo out because the session was updated on the 1st session and not yet available until the next page reload.

So how can I achieve what I want?  I hope this makes sense...

thanks!

Comment: seems like your sequence of showing the form and saving the data to session is wrong, can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just wanting to be able to know if the form was submitted?

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['field1'] = $_POST['field1'];
    echo "field1 = " . $_SESSION['field1'];
} else {
    // show form here
}
?>
```

Comment: dtbarne - no, when the form gets submitted the data gets processed and is adding to the session variable..So after the form is submitted, I need to show the results of the data to the user.

Comment: Ok, so just add that code directory after you add it to the $_SESSION variables. As others have noted, a code sample is necessary for any further help.

Answer (score 0):

Session data is actually stored on the server so you don't need to refresh the page to access the data in the session.

Comment: Brian - yes i know what a session is but this does not help what i am trying to do..

Comment: @Rick: Can you post a code sample, we'll be able to help more if we know what's going on.

Comment: Brian - yeah unfortunately it is a plugin I am using and therefore I wouldn't know what codes to copy as I don't know how the plugin is handling the sessions...

Answer (score 0):

try like this. i just created an example.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php 

if (isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action'] == 'Engaged')) {
    $_SESSION["try"] = 2; 
}               
echo $_SESSION["try"]; // print after saving or doing the action
?>    
<form action="" method="post" name="record">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Engaged" name="action" /> 
                            </td>                       
    </tr>

    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```